# Is there a good EC2 image for a microinstance that includes just ruby but not rails,mysql, etc

Tags: ruby, amazon-ec2

I just want to spool up some micro-instances and install a few gems.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you just start an instance of a clean base AMI running the Linux distro of your preference from a trusted source.  Then run the standard commands (e.g., apt-get, yum) to install the standard Ruby provided by the distro and go from there.

You don't need to find an AMI that has exactly the set of packages you want to run.  Modern Linux makes it easy to install these cleanly.

With AMIs like the official Ubuntu or Amazon Linux you can even pass in a script as user-data and it will run it on first boot. You can use this to make sure that your desired packages and gems are installed when the instance runs.